# Mobile device Anchor Tag in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, hyperlink, anchor

I added an anchor tag in a Wordpress site that works fine on a computer, but not on a mobile.

I've been searching and saw that jquery is needed, but I'm a bit confused on how to add it in Wordpress. If anyone could, that would be awesome :)

Comment: Why would jQuery be needed to use an anchor ?

Comment: For mobile devices? I'm not sure, that's the only thing I could find.